# Add multiple HTTP Interceptors to Angular Application

Tags: angular, http, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

How to add multiple, independent HTTP interceptors to an Angular 4 application?

I tried to add them by extending the `providers` array with more than one interceptors. But only the last one is actually executed, `Interceptor1` is ignored.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ /* ... */ ],
  imports: [ /* ... */ HttpModule ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) =>
        new Interceptor1(xhrBackend, requestOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions],
    },
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) =>
        new Interceptor2(xhrBackend, requestOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I could obviously combine them into a single `Interceptor` class and that should work. However, I would like to avoid that as these interceptors have completely different purposes (one for error handling, one to show a loading indicator).

So how can I add multiple interceptors?

Comment: You're overriding `Http`. Only last override is used. Interceptor1 is not ignored, it's just non-existent. You can use HttpClient that has interceptors included.

Comment: @estus What do you mean by "You can use HttpClient that has interceptors included."?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: you can use different interceptors for request, response using [this](https://github.com/gund/ng-http-interceptor) with that you can do error handling, loader indicator.

Comment: Is there any update on this question?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`Http` doesn't allow to have more than one custom implementation. But as @estus mentioned the Angular team has added a new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) service recently (release 4.3) which supports multiple interceptors concept. You don't need to extend the `HttpClient` as you do with the old `Http`. You can provide an implementation for `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` instead which can be an array with the `'multi: true'` option:

```
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ... ,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ... ,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorOne,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorTwo,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
  ...
})
```

Interceptors:

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
...

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorOne implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('InterceptorOne is working');
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorTwo implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('InterceptorTwo is working');
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

This server call will print both interceptors' log messages:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
...

@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://some_url').subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to tell `api` call can be intercept by only one `interceptor` ? or by any conditions ?

Comment: @k11k2 and for everyone searching, here is a question and answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781379/how-to-add-httpclient-interceptors-conditionally-in-angular
I admit I'm still a bit confused about it.

Comment: Why has to be @Injectable()? It works without @Injectable() for me

Comment: @makkasi: Need to add@Injectable if the interceptor class needs to do any dependency injection of its own. In the given example, it is not required

Comment: How to fix about interceptors ordering?

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha Interceptors are called in the order in which they are provided